# Sitecore site configuration requireLogin not working

Tags: site-configuration

If I wanted to force users to go through a login for the entire site. I would previously add `requireLogin` and `loginPage` attributes to my site configuration.

In 8.2 I am unable to do this. However in 8.1 this works. Any ideas how this has changed? Or am I doing something wrong and missing something.

```
<site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="loginPage">/sitecore modules/shell/login.aspx</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="requireLogin">true</patch:attribute>
</site>
```

The attributes work for admin site configuration.

Read access for `extranet/anonymous` was removed for the protected area of the page as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check that you denied access to `extranet\Anonymous`, rather than to other anonymous accounts. Then open the site in incognito mode, because you already have a logged-in admin session on the site. Please come back with results.

Comment: Can confirm this has been reproduced by Sitecores own team. Awaiting response @DmytroShevchenko

Comment: Can confirm this was due to custom code, not an issue with sitecore :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell which areas of your site require the login.

Remove read access for `extranet/anonymous` user for the item which should be protected with login.

Comment: This is also true, I did this already and am still getting the issue. I have raised a question with sitecore support.

Comment: Ok, I have added this to the answer.

Comment: I will add to this that after you deny Read Permission to say Home item for extranet\Anonymous user. You need to publish master database to web to get this working.